# Rescue/capture ctrl-break

Tags: ruby

How do I catch the exception raised by the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>break</kbd> key combination? 
I'm running a ruby program on windows (inside of `cmd.exe`), and I capture <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> fine with something like this:

```
rescue Interrupt
    puts 'Doing cleanup task before exiting'
    raise
```

I have cleanup task to do before the program exits (deleting a file), and this works with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>. If I exit the program with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>break</kbd>, the exception is not caught, and it just terminates after showing `^C` in the console.

Sometimes my program gets to a state where <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> is not responsive, and I have to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>break</kbd> to close it, but I would still like my rescue function to act. Is there another exception type I need to capture?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ctrl+break is the windows equivalent of `kill -9`, right? In that case, no it can't be captured.

Comment: I'm not sure that is entirely the case.  It should still be sending a SIGBREAK.  According to this http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/578130-control-c-alternative-windows it defaults to Win32 ExitProcess() but Python's signal module provides a way to trap this and remap it to SIGINT, so some languages definitely have workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>break</kbd> sends `SIGBREAK`, so this would be the expected way to handle it:

```
trap("BREAK") { puts "ctrl-break" }
```

Unfortunately, Ruby doesn't know `(SIG)BREAK`, so you have to use the signal number instead, which should be `21`:

```
trap(21) { puts "ctrl-break" }
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> can be handled accordingly, i.e.:

```
trap("INT") { puts "ctrl-c" }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I have to trap it instead of just rescue it.

Answer (score 0):

As of Ruby 2.0, I don't think it is supported.

```
Signal.trap("SIGBREAK") do
  puts "captured!"
end

ArgumentError: unsupported signal SIGBREAK
```